# Prove that if $p$ is a prime and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, then $p \mid n^p - n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that if $p$ is a prime and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, then $p \mid n^p - n$

Hints:

Use a previously proven theorem that for prime $p$ and $0 < a < p$, then $p \mid \binom{p}{a}$

Use induction on $n$ and the binomial theorem with $x=k,y=1$

\begin{align*}
  (x+y)^n &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k y^{n-k}\\
\end{align*}

My Work:

The formula can be easily verified for $n = 1$ since $p \mid 0$

I'm having trouble seeing how to set up the induction or use the binomial theorem as the hints suggest.

Comment: The hints specifically ask you to consider the binomial theorem with $x=k$, $y=1$.  Have you actually tried this?  You don't mention in your question any effort to follow the hint.

Comment: $k$ is the loop iteration variable. I don't understand how to set $x=k$ and how that would work in the binomial theorem.

Comment: You want exponent $p$ in the binomial theorem, not $n$.

Comment: I'm thinking this would be easier to prove using Fermat's little theorem: $n^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ means $n^p \equiv n \bmod p$ therefore $n^p - n \equiv n - n \equiv 0 \bmod p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By induction hypothesis $n^p-n=p\cdot d$

It is easy to see that $p|{p\choose k}$ if $1\leq k \leq p-1$

\begin{eqnarray*}
  (n+1)^p-(n+1) &=& n^p + \underbrace{{p\choose 1}n^{p-1}+...+{p\choose p-1}n}_a+1-n-1 \\
   &=& \underbrace{n^p-n}_{p\cdot d} + p\cdot b \\
 &=& p (d+b)
  \end{eqnarray*}
where $a = p\cdot b$

Answer (score 3):

The fact that $p |\dfrac{p!}{a!(p-a)!}$ is true because $p$ is prime and $p>a$, so $p$ can't divide neither $a!$ nor $(p-a)!$ and $p|p!$

Next:

$n^p = (1+1+1+...+1)^p$. Using binomial coefficients for this equation and the fact that $p$ $|$ ${p}\choose{a}$, we are getting:

$n^p = (1+1+1+...+1)^p$

$(1+1+1+...+1)^p = (1^p +...+1^p) \mod p$ (this is true because $p|$${p}\choose{a}$)

$(1^p +...+1^p)=(1+...+1) \mod p$

So $n^p = n \mod p$, hence $p | (n^p - n)$

Comment: Using binomial coefficients is a bit vague here: are you doing a multinomial expansion or applying the binomial theorem recursively?  While not every answer must cater to the OP, this seems to be glossing over a detail that is central to the OP's question.